# Mysql: Sort an aggregate ascending with zeros last

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to sort an aggregate column, which contains some zero values. I need the zero values to be last.

For non-aggregate columns I can do something like this (simplified example query):

```
SELECT age FROM books 
ORDER BY 
age = 0,
age ASC
```

However, for aggregate columns I'm getting an error as the column doesn't exist:

```
SELECT avg(age) as avg_age FROM books 
GROUP BY book.type 
ORDER BY 
avg_age = 0,
avg_age ASC
```

The error is:
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1247 Reference 'avg_age' not supported (reference to group function)`

I totally appreciate *why* this is happening, but I wasn't able to find a workaround, any tips?

Comment: There seams to be a (old) [existing](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80802) MySQL bug report about your question?

Comment: Aha, I'm not going crazy then! So it seems you can use the aggregate within the ORDER BY clause in that case, I'll give that a go. Tediously this is part of a reasonably large reporting framework, and it's not going to be quite as simple as "Duplicate the aggregate in the sort by" but if that is what is needed....

Comment: Awesome - I'm using MariaDB 10 at the moment, perhaps I'll just upgrade that. Thank you!

Comment: You would have the write `SELECT avg(age) as avg_age FROM books 
GROUP BY books.type 
ORDER BY 
avg(age) = 0,
avg(age) ASC`  see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/noeKsDCC7s4Lxi7nc4fagB/0)... Also this is fixed in MySQL 8 see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/noeKsDCC7s4Lxi7nc4fagB/0) .. But ideally you should repeat the `avg(age)` part in the `ORDER BY` to make the query ANSI/ISO SQL standards proof which means your query is most likely then better portable between databases vendor software.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland - If you post that as an answer I'll accept, you were quicker than the current answer and you've been more helpful with your additional context. Thank you!

Comment: *"If you post that as an answer I'll accept"* Ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seams to be a (old) related bug report

> [21 Mar 2016 9:22] Jiří Kavalík
>
> Description: When using alias to aggregated column in ORDER BY only
>   plain alias is allowed, using it in any expression returns error.
>
> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e87bb/7
>
> Workarounds:
>   - select the expression and use its alias
>   - use a derived table and order the outer one
>
> How to repeat: create table t(a int);
>   -- these work select sum(a) x from t group by a order by x; select sum(a) x from t group by a order by sum(a); select sum(a) x from t
>   group by a order by -sum(a);
>
> -- this one wrongly gives "Reference 'x' not supported (reference to group function)" select sum(a) x from t group by a order by -x;

[source](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80802)

You would have to write, this is better as the query is then also  ANSI/ISO SQL standard valid meaning the query is most likely better portable between most databases vendor software.

```
SELECT
  avg(books.age) as avg_age
FROM books
GROUP BY books.type
ORDER BY
  avg(books.age) = 0
, avg(books.age) ASC
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/noeKsDCC7s4Lxi7nc4fagB/0) this bug is fixed in MySQL 8.0 see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/noeKsDCC7s4Lxi7nc4fagB/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try repeating the code

```
SELECT avg(age) as avg_age 
FROM books 
GROUP BY book.type 
ORDER BY avg(age) = 0, avg(age) ASC
```